# How to split string of index in list and store within same list?

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a list like this:

`lst = ['apple orange', 'banana', 'grape']`

I know that `list[0].split()` will only return a list containing `['apple', 'orange']` but I would like to achieve the following in a simplistic sol'n:

`lst = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape']`

---

Example 2:

Let's say the list is:

`lst = ['apple orange', 'banana', 'grape', 'foo fi']`

and I only want

`lst = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape', 'foo fi']`

how can I do that in a one-line sol'n?

(If some context helps, lets assume that it will not always be in index position 0)

Comment: To clarify, you only want the first string split up?

Comment: Added some context, but the index will be identified on some other criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension that will mimic unpacking:

```
lst = ['apple orange', 'banana', 'grape']
new_lst = [w for s in lst for w in s.split()]
print(new_lst)
# ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape']
```

It is the equivalent of this more concise but invalid version:

```
new_lst = [*s.split() for s in lst]
```

Unfortunately, unpacking like this isn't allowed in list comprehensions, which is why we must use the workaround above.

Edited question solution:

```
index = 1 # or whatever
lst = ['banana', 'apple orange', 'grape']
lst[index:index + 1] = lst[index].split()
print(lst)
```

The above works in-place; if you wanted to create a copy you could either use the above but make a copy or:

```
index = 1 # or whatever
lst = ['banana', 'apple orange', 'grape']
new_lst = lst[:index] + lst[index].split() + lst[index + 1:]
print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

For you second question, you may use `slicing`

```
def split_at(l, i):
    return l[:i] + l[i].split() + l[i+1:]
```

For example:

```
>>> split_at(l,0)
['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape', 'foo fi']

>>> split_at(l,3)
['apple orange', 'banana', 'grape', 'foo', 'fi']
```